# Crystal Reports text cuts off last line in Details section

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report 11 file that is a letter. The first Details section contains a large text box that has print date, address block, and the salutation line. Every once in a while, the last line of the text box gets cut off so that the salutation isn't seen. It's very inconsistent in that sometimes, I run the report for one person in my system and the text is cut off, but if I run the report a few hours later for the same person, without having changed the values of the address or name in my database, then the letter looks fine.

I increased the text box height and the Details section height, but the problem still occurs intermittently. Has this happened to anyone else, or does anyone have an idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Is this on the screen, or when you print it out? What Crystal displays on the screen depends on which printer you are going to use. Did you change your default printer in between the two times?

Answer (score 2):

Normally this should be working if you check the "Can Grow" option in the common tab of the "Format Field/Text" settings. With that option checked it shouldn't matter which height you set.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult problem that you have to attack from 3 different fronts:

1. Software Hot Fix
2. Default Printer
3. Form Authoring

**Software Hot Fix:**  You'll need to download the CRRuntime that includes Hot Fix 20.  This Hot Fix addresses truncation problems when making a PDF.  You can find it at http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/crnetruntime/clickonce/CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_20.msi

**Default Printer:**  The printer you use when authoring a report must match a printer when you are rendering a report.  On our servers, there are no printers installed except the Microsoft XPS Document Writer.  Be sure to select that as your default printer when writing the report.

**Form Authoring:** When you add a database field to your report, don't drag it from the field explorer onto the design surface.  First insert a text object onto the design surface.  When you've positioned and sized it, then drag the database field onto the Text Object.  For whatever reason, the database field will wrap better when it is enclosed by a text object.